# Growing a trimmed holly as a tree

Tags: trees, pruning, evergreens

I bought a holly (Oakland) that I wanted online because I could not find it locally.

The nursery trimmed and shaped it nicely before shipping including cutting the central leader.

I want this to grow freely as a tree and not a regularly manicured shrub.

Will this still be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it shouldn't be a problem. This particular variety has a natural tendency to grow in a pyramid shape, and hollies generally exhibit strong apical domination, so the removal of the central leader just means another one or two will appear. This variety is said to get between 15 and 20 feet tall, with a spread of 8-15 feet.

Comment: Thank you, that is reassuring to know.